# ALFA AWUS036AXM usb wifi adapter generating xhci_hcd transfer error

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, 22.04, virtualbox

### Setup

- Ubuntu 22.04 (kernel 6.3.5) guest running on VirtualBox VM
- MacOS (Big Sur) Host
- ALFA AWUS036AXM connected via USB (Mediatek MT7921aun chipset). it is [recommended for Linux](https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi/blob/main/home/USB_WiFi_Chipsets.md)

The VM detects the Wifi adapter fine

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 0e8d:7961 MediaTek Inc. Wireless_Device
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

When I run airodump-ng, it does work (although not convinced it is stable/reliable), however there are many error being generated identical to:

```
$ dmesg | grep xhci
[44519.918798] xhci_hcd 0000:00:0c.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 8 comp_code 13
[44519.918858] xhci_hcd 0000:00:0c.0: Looking for event-dma 00000000160e5bb0 trb-start 00000000160e5bc0 trb-end 00000000160e5bf0 seg-start 00000000160e5000 seg-end 00000000160e5ff0
```

If I use another ALFA adapter, AWUS036AC (with [aircrack driver](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au)) then there are no errors

Answer (score -1):

Note it was confirmed that it does not happen on bare metal Ubuntu install as per https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi/issues/323

Comment: That is to say it only suspense on virtual machines.